# Repo rate in GBM

Tags: black-scholes

I have seen people use $\mu = r_f - repo$ in GBM.

1, Why do we subtract repo from risk free rate?
2, Is the stock price still a martingale?

Comment: May I know what is repo?

Comment: Repo rate. In a repo, the dealer sells the underlying security to investors and buys them back shortly afterwards, usually the following day, at a slightly higher price.